# undefined method `fulltext'` and `keywords` on sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I got `NoMethodError (undefined method`fulltext'`and`NoMethodError (undefined method `keywords'`

I followed the documentation, But not knowing what's wrong with it.

Is it conflicted with `ransack` ?

### Form

```
  = form_tag search_index_path, :method => :get, :target => '_blank', class: 'form-control navbar-form navbar-right form-inline' do
    = text_field_tag :query, params[:query], :placeholder => "Search .."
```

### Controller

```
@query_results = Sunspot.search(Tool::Mvaas::RelayQuery) do |query|
  keywords params[:query]
  fulltext params[:query]
end
```

### Model Tool::Mvaas::RelayQuery

```
  class Tool::Mvaas::RelayQuery < ActiveRecord::Base
    searchable do
      text :request, :comment
    end
  end
```

### Gem

```
  gem "sunspot_rails"
  gem "sunspot_solr"
  gem "ransack"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a stupid error

I shouldn't use the `@query_results = Sunspot.search(Tool::Mvaas::RelayQuery) do |query|`

I should remove the parameter `|query|` use `@query_results = Sunspot.search(Tool::Mvaas::RelayQuery) do`